# Continuity with left and right hand limits

Tags: real-analysis

Just for a general argument, I want to show left hand limit = right hand limit implies limit exists. I can do this by considering an epsilon neighborhood around the point from the left and then an epsilon neighborhood on the right hand side and then put them together. Is this a good outline?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: Trying to fix it, sorry.

Comment: If you want to know the definitions, please google about them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the idea is correct: formally we have
$
0 < |x-c| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)| < \varepsilon
$
iff
$-\delta < x -c < 0 \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)| < \varepsilon$
and
$0 < x-c < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)| < \varepsilon$.